# How does excessive acute inflammation damage tissue (eg, in sepsis or cytokine release syndrome)?

Tags: inflammation, sepsis

While inflammation is necessary to recruit immune cells to sites of infection in order to clear the etiological agent of disease, excessive inflammation has often been implicated in many of the poor outcomes associated with systemic infection, specifically end-stage organ failure (eg, in sepsis).

However, what is not clear to me is what the effector mechanisms of excessive inflammation are which mediate the tissue damage necessary to cause the organ damage. It's very clear to me that excessive signaling through neutrophils can, through positive feedback loops, create a large amount of systematically circulating inflammatory cytokines. But what's less clear to me is what the link is between extremely high levels of cytokines and the ultimate tissue damage associated with excessive inflammation. Presumably, it cannot be due to the direct effector functions of humoral responses or cell-based responses, as both antibodies as well as TCRs are exquisitely specific to foreign antigens. One common explanation is excessive fluid accumulation in tissue due to enhanced vascular permeability - a classic feature of the inflammatory cascade and necessary to allow leukocytes to enter the tissue space. But are there other effector mechanisms by which excessively high pro-inflammatory cytokine levels cause tissue damage?

In short then, while I understanding the pathogen --> inflammatory cytokine secretion stage, what I don't understand well is the inflammatory cytokine secretion --> ?? --> organ damage.

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepsis
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytokine_release_syndrome

Comment: You can assume there are no effective antibodies. See [immune response to respiratory virus: balancing virus clearance and immunopathology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4896975/). This [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5624992/) explains how cell suicide with in the same time call for phagocytes to clear the nearly dead cell is the normal way to eliminate infected cells and hence the virus. The inflammation enhances those processes but supposedly in a tightly controlled way.